# Problem with a list when I do edit it myself and not by a python package

Tags: python, list

```
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger
from transformers import pipeline

class Klassensetzer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-german-large")
        self.classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
        self.content=None

    def TK_model(self,content):
        sentence = Sentence(content)
        self.tagger.predict(sentence)
        self.content=(sentence.get_spans('ner'))
        return self.content

K=Klassensetzer()
solu1=K.TK_model("Augustus besucht Berlin")
#Means Augustus visits Berlin

print(solu1)
#Output:         [Span[0:1]: "Augustus" → PER (1.0), Span[2:3]: "Berlin" → LOC (1.0)]

#Does work out

solu2=[Span[0:1]: "Augustus" → PER (1.0), Span[2:3]: "Berlin" → LOC (1.0)]
print(solu2)
#Output:         SyntaxError: invalid syntax

#Didn't worked out after the second use
```

I used the output to faster improve my code, but it didn't work out.
I used this python_package, but it takes to long to debug other things, so I just safed the output. The output given by the API is not a String, but a list, I could access the variables:

```
for i in solu2:
     print(i)
```

I can't find my mistake.

When starting the following lines of code a second time, I tried to make shure these were the same I used the first time.

```
solu2=[Span[0:1]: "Augustus" → PER (1.0), Span[2:3]: "Berlin" → LOC (1.0)]
print(solu2)
#Output:         SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Look out for wether the output of the python_package is a string or not.

Thank you and I hope I didn't make a silly mistake

Comment: You have a class. It is printing based on the internal representation of what's passed to it, which appears to be a list of `Sentence Span`'s. You can't just 'assign' what you got as output back to a list and expect it to work. print is not a 'two way' output/input mechanism, it's an output mechanism only. You would need to construct an array of `Sentence Span`'s to have this work.